# How do I get my progress bar to iterate while a script is being executed?

Tags: python, progress-bar, python-3.6

I created a ui that runs a python script on a button click.  I included a progress bar to confirm when the script has completed.  I'm not sure I have the code correct because when I click the button to execute the script, the progress bar instantly shows 100%.  However, the script that's executing the code is still running in the background and completes a few seconds later.

I setup the ui using qt designer.  I'm running python 3.6  Below is a snippet of the progress bar code:

```
def progress(self):
        loop_count = 100
        self.progressBar.setValue(loop_count)
        
        while True:
            #the script that's executing based o the button click
            with open("Python-Test1.py") as f:
                 exec(f.read())
                 loop_count += 1
                 if loop_count >= 100:
                     break
                 time.sleep(1)
```

I've tried changing the time.sleep setting from 1 to 0.1, 0.00001.  I've tried changing the code for the progress bar to the following:

```
def progress(self):
     count = 100
       for i in range(100):
             count += 1
             self.progressBar.setValue(count)
             #the script that's executing based o the button click
             subprocess.run(['python', 'Python-Test1.py'])
             time.sleep(0.1) 
             with open("Python-Test1.py") as f:
                 exec(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try another module, like tqdm:

```
pip install tqdm
```

It is something really direct, like:

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    sleep(3)
```

Comment: tqdm is great but for what I'm hoping to accomplish, it's not as straight forward.  When I click the button in the gui, I'm expecting another script to kick off and the progress bar to display.  I found another way to implement the progress bar.  I'm not sure how to join the code for the progress bar to the code for the script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use threading.

```
import threading
def progress(self):
    loop_count = 100
    self.progressBar.setValue(loop_count)

    while loop_count <= 100:
        #the script that's executing based o the button click
        with open("Python-Test1.py") as f:
             exec(f.read())
             loop_count += 1
             time.sleep(1)

# Start whatever where the progress bar is needed
t = threading.Thread(target=progress)
t.start()
# Run whatever you need, the progress bar should be running

#...
```

Comment: [`threading` is part of Python's standard library](https://docs.python.org/library/threading.html). It is [not available on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/threading/), so `pip install`ing it won't work.

Comment: ok, well yes, but also would that mean **most** interpreters would automatically have it?

Comment: Yes, it should be available in a proper CPython installation.